# When does sql exclusively lock a row in an update statement?

Tags: sql, multithreading, synchronization

Can a race condition occur in sql under these conditions?

If I have this SQL update running in one thread call it statement 1:

```
Update Items
Set Flag = B
where Flag = A;
```

And this SQL update running in another call it statement 2:

```
Update Items
Set Flag = C
where Flag = A;
```

Is it possible for each thread to read the same record where Flag is equal to A and write the record with their own values?  Such that statement 1 can write it first and then statement 2 writes it or visa versa?

The answer to this question depends on when the database exclusively locks the update.  Does it happen before it finds the records or after it finds the records and evaluates the where clause?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: The second statement will wait until the first one is committed. And it's **really** easy to try that out with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c21cnsis.htm

Answer (score 5):

First, there are three lock contexts:

- Database level lock
- Table level lock
- Row level lock

Then you have four lock modes:

- IX
- IS
- X
- S

IX and IS locks are "intention" locks.  These locks are held before acquiring other types of locks.  X locks are exclusive (write) locks and S locks are shared (read) locks.

The locks (IX,IS,X or S) locks can be taken at any context level.  An X lock at the database level will block all other operations in the database for example.  This is the type of lock that SQLlite takes.  An S lock is taken for the entire database during reads, and an X lock is taken for the entire database during writes.  Writes will wait for any S locks to complete and will block new S and X locks until the write lock is released.  This provides a serializable isolation transaction level.

For MySQL, the locking depends on the storage engine.  MyISAM will take X and S locks on entire (sets of) tables.  X locks will wait on existing S or X locks and block new locks.  New X locks will be given higher priority in the queue, moved ahead of new S locks.  This behavior can be changed by setting LOW_PRIORITY_UPDATES, which could result in write starvation because writes will be de-prioritized in favor of reads.

It is possible in MySQL to obtain an X lock over the entire database using 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK'.

InnoDB locks rows as they are encountered via an index read.  InnoDB locks index records and locks the records when the index records are traversed.  InnoDB uses special locks called 'gap' locks to ensure REPEATABLE-READ transaction isolation level.  Locks are held on index entries, so if a table is not well indexed for an UPDATE query, then many rows will be locked.  Note that InnoDB does not create S locks for normal SELECT queries.  It uses row versioning, not row level locking for consistent snapshots.

When acquiring X locks, the database needs to detect deadlocks.  Consider the following:

```
>connection 1
start transaction;
update T set c = c + 1 order by id asc;

>connection 2
start transaction;
update T set c = c - 1 order by id desc;
```

In a row locking model, these two statements can not both complete successfully.  The first would wait forever to acquire locks the second holds, and vice-versa.  The database will pick one of the connections to roll back.  InnoDB will pick the connection which has made the fewest number of changes.  MyISAM will lock the whole table for whichever connection acquires the lock first, and then the second will run after the first completes.

The simple example given by you will be resolved by X locks at any context (database, table or row).  If two connections begin at exactly the same type, both running two updates which try to update the same row, both will attempt to acquire an X lock.  Only one connection can acquire the X lock.  It is not possible to determine exactly which one will acquire the lock.  The other connection will have to wait until the lock is released until it can acquire the X lock.  Keep in mind, that if the row was locked by a DELETE or UPDATE, then the waiter might end up not acquiring a lock after waiting, because there is nothing left in the database to lock.

In your example, the first UPDATE to acquire the X lock, and the second UPDATE will then wait on the X lock and will eventually execute but not match any rows.

Comment: Yes, but when do they attempt to acquire the X lock? Before the where clause is evaluated or after?  That's what I'm attempting to understand.

Comment: It depends on the database.  If you use SQLlite, then the X lock is acquired before the WHERE clause is evaluated, because the lock is DATABASE level.  If you use MyISAM, the X lock is taken before the WHERE clause is evaluated, because the X clause is a TABLE level lock.  If you use InnoDB (row level locks), then the X lock(s) are taken during evaluation of the WHERE clause, because you can't figure out which rows to lock without finding the rows by evaluating the WHERE clause.  That is why you get serialization of the updates with MyISAM, but a deadlock with InnoDB in my deadlock example.

Comment: So on InnoDB, would it first evaluate the row condition and then when it has a match acquire the lock before writing?

Comment: It will lock all the index entries it traverses to find the rows.  This means that an update that is not well indexed will lock more rows than you expect.  The index entries are locked, not the rows themselves in InnoDB.  How row level locks are taken is database dependent, but they are always taken in such a way so that no race that you are worried about can happen.  Some databases (like berkley db) use page level locking, for example, and lock all records on each page they encounter.

Comment: `mysql> start transaction; update t set c2 = c2 + 1 where c2 = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0`

Comment: 9 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 4105 row lock(s), undo log entries 1

Comment: You can see, the UPDATE statement only changed one row, but 4105 locks were set.

Comment: Those extra row locks were set because InnoDB locked all the records, because it had to traverse the primary key to find each row, while applying the WHERE clause.  InnoDB locks records on the index entries it traverses to satisfy the WHERE clause, not only the records which match the WHERE clause (in REPEATABLE READ isolation level).  In READ-COMMITTED, InnoDB will release the locks on the rows that did not match the WHERE condition, but ONLY AFTER the statement completes, to prevent a race.

Comment: Justin thanks.  I appreciate the lengths you've gone through to explain this. It's very kind of you.

Comment: Is it possible those 4105 locks are shared locks, but not until it writes does it attempt for an exclusive lock.  I saw in SQL Server that have an update lock which permits shared reading until the exclusive lock is acquired.  I guess I still have some doubts about the behaviors in all instances.  They did this to prevent deadlock conditions when moving from the shared lock to the exclusive.

Comment: In MySQL it is possible to acquire an S lock over rows with SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE;  You can then upgrade to X lock with either UPDATE or SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;

Answer (score 0):

Exclusive lock, used for data-modification operations, such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE will be used in this scenario.

An exclusive lock ensures that multiple updates cannot be made to the same resource at the same time.

You will not get a race condition in this scenario.

If you have a more complex scenario involving multiple tables then you may get race conditions, or deadlocks.  There are many ways to avoid this, simplifying and separating queries, etc.

You can also apply hints to queries that tell SQL what type of lock to use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: So the exclusive lock is raised prior to finding the records that match the where clause?  Do we know that for sure?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should read about locking.  SQL server has a complex set of logic and will perform either table or row level locks based on the number of rows it estimates will require updates. Unless you specifically tell it which you want it to perform it can even vary from query to query.  Usually if you are modifying a small subset of the table it will choose a row level lock.

SQL Server is designed with ACID in mind, thus it writes changes to its logs before performing any actual updates to the data.  This allows any failed updates to be rolled back and allows consistency between queries (like your asking about).  You can perform dirty reads to get around locking issues, however you cannot prevent SQL Server from locking inserted, updated and/or deleted records.

[SQL Server Locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

EDIT: Here is an article about ACID.
[ACID - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity)

Answer (score 0):

All SQL databases pretty much guarantee that such a collision will not occur.  "When" locking occurs depends on whether locking is at the table, partition, page, or row level.  Or, whether you have turned off such locking in your database.

What can happen, if you have concurrent update statements and multiple rows being updated, is that sone row are updated with the first, some with the second.

In general, I think of the where clause as being evaluated to select the row set, lock the rows one at a time, do the update and unlock.  However, this depends on the type of locking.  In this case, the scenario above would continue with the values flipping.

If you are concerned about this situation, use table level locking to force serialization when concurrent update requests are being processed.

Comment: No SQL standard compliant database will "flip" the values.  The first statement to execute will acquire locks, change the values and release the locks on commit.  Some databases will take extra locks.  For example, depending on the transaction isolation level, the "gaps" before and after ranges may have to be locked.

Comment: I did not say that was standard behavior.  In any case, this is my confusion.  Read uncommitted hints are allowed in at least one database (SQL Server) on updates ... But the hint is ignored.

Comment: In some databases MVCC is used for SELECT statements, but not for other DML.  MySQL InnoDB non-SELECT DML is "semi-repeatable" read for this reason, as the most up-to-date version of a row is always presented to non-SELECT statements.  Under no circumstances can a situation arises where two connections obtain an X lock on the same row.  If that happens, then a deadlock must be declared.

Comment: Just to be clear, the question is not about two locks on the same row.  It is about whether an update query locks all rows first, then does the updates, then unlocks them (which is the right behavior).  Or whether you can set up delayed locking, which only locks a row when it is about to be updated.  It seems that the first approach requires a table-level write lock during the locking process, and I thought some databases let you get around that.  Note:  this does not have any effect on single row updates.

Comment: You don't have to "lock all rows" then "update all rows".  You lock rows as you encounter them, changing them, copying old versions into rollback segments (or whatever your RDBMS calls them) and writing new versions into REDO logs.  If, while acquiring locks you encounter a lock wait timeout waiting on locks from another connection, then you rollback the changes (using the rollback segments) and release the locks.  If you deadlock trying to acquire your locks, then you rollback the transaction or the statement, depending on the RDBMS.

Comment: If you want to explicitly lock all rows as the programmer, you are allowed to.  To get a shared lock use SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE.  To get exclusive locks use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;